# .attr() get <img> content

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, each

I have a application that is using Jquery UI. to create a drag and drop sortable picture list. These pictures are inserted in to the `<li>` of a `<ul>`. Through the below code, I am able to loop through, receiving the contents of each listed li, but not the contents of the `<img>` tag.

```
$(function() {
$( "#sortable" ).sortable();
$( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
$( "#savebutton" ).click(function() { LISTOBJ.saveList(); });
});

var LISTOBJ = {
    saveList: function() {
        var listCSV = "";
        $( "#sortable li" ).each(function() {
            if (listCSV === "") {
                listCSV = $(this).text();
            } else {
                listCSV += "," + $(this).text();
            }
            $("#output").text(listCSV);
            $("#hiddenListInput").val(listCSV);
            //$("#listsaveform").submit();
        });
    }
}
```

My question is - Why can I see the contents of the `<li>`, but not of the img tag inside it? I believe the answer lies somewhere in adding a .attr() to the .each, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Does anyone know what I am missing, or if I am even on the right track?

Comment: What do you mean by contents of the img tag "inside it"? `img` has nothing inside it, just attributes.

Comment: Yeah, Grant is right. Are you sure you don't mean that you want the src attribute of the <img> tag? Maybe you could show the HTML of the list you're looping?

Comment: You are asking for the text contents of the `li` rather than the html contents, which will include the `img` tag. If you want to capture the src of the child `img`, you'll have to grab `$(this).find('img').attr('src')`

Comment: use the `.html()` instead of `.text()`.

Comment: I did want the Src. Looks like Chumkiu answered it perfectly. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `html()` instead of `text()` in order to get all `<img>` tag

```
        if (listCSV === "") {
            listCSV = $(this).html();
        } else {
            listCSV += "," + $(this).html();
        }
```

or if you want only the `src` attribute

```
        if (listCSV === "") {
            listCSV = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
        } else {
            listCSV += "," + $(this).find('img').attr('src');
        }
```